# How Mapping Routes in React Router with Protected Function?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I Try To Handling my code with React Route in map and protected function;

This The array for components;

```
import LoginContainers from "../Containers/LoginContainers/LoginContainers";
import RegisterContainers from "../Containers/RegisterContainers/RegisterContainers";
import ChattingApp from "../Containers/ChattingApp/ChattingApp";

const RoutesMaster = [
    {
        Path: '/login',
        Component: LoginContainers,
        Title: 'Login',
        AuthRequired: false
    },{
        Path: '/register',
        Component: RegisterContainers,
        Title: 'Register',
        AuthRequired: true
    },{
        Path: '/',
        Component: ChattingApp,
        Title: 'Janus Chat',
        AuthRequired: true
    },
]
```

And this the code in main component;

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import RoutesMaster from "./RoutesMaster";

const RoutesRender = (Routes, Key) => {
    const History = useHistory();

    if (Routes.AuthRequired) {
        History.push("/auth/login");
    } else {
        return (
            <Route exact key={Key} path={Routes.Path} render={(props) => <Routes.Component {...props} />} />
        )
    }
}

const RoutesProvider = () => {
    return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                {RoutesMaster.map((Routes, Index) => (
                    <RoutesRender Routes={Routes} Key={Index} />
                ))}
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.Fragment>
);
}

export default RoutesProvider;
```

But it's show this message;
**"Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `Router.Consumer`."**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning undefined, or rather returning nothing in method `RoutesRender`, and react requires you to return in VDOM at least `null`.

Here is your code with change and comment to see where it is:

```js
const RoutesRender = ({ Routes, Key}) => {
  const History = useHistory();

  if (Routes.AuthRequired) {
    History.push('/auth/login');
    return null; // This is return value that is needed
  } else {
    return <Route exact key={Key} path={Routes.Path} render={(props) => <Routes.Component {...props} />} />;
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add code for other components. Maybe there you don't return component content

Comment: if i put Route inside map it's work but if i put in function not work

Comment: {RoutesMaster.map((Routes, Index) => (
                        <Route exact key={Index} path={Routes.Path} render={(props) => <Routes.Component {...props} />} />
                    ))}

Comment: this is work but i need to add it in function

Comment: I cannot connect the dots like this. Can you add full code that works please?

Comment: https://github.com/LinkedForest/JanusChat/blob/master/resources/Routes/RoutesProvider.jsx

Comment: Thanks. So in this repo is code that does not work? You mentioned that you found way of making it work. Can you add that code here in commet or update repo?

Comment: I will try something else and come back to you

Comment: @RamyMohamed edited my answer. So you were taking props in a wrong way. So first prop is the main one that contains all props for that component. So I destructed all properties from that one. Now it does not show any error

Comment: Thank you for your time, I try it put looping not working just show first object from array

Comment: I mad a codesandbox for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-sun-0ewy8?file=/src/App.js:1123-1128

Comment: Open up the Console and you will see there is no error that you talked about. That was your original problem. I made example only with code you presented. You can add that code to your project and continue in your code so that you can see full effect

Comment: Thanks For your time, and your helping